# Focus Button by default on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

Attempting a vanilla js solution to focus .btn-1 by default on page load.

Can't figure out why I keep getting this error :  `index.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).focus is not a function at window.onload (index.js:2)`

Anyone have thoughts on this please?

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

    <button class="btn btn-1">1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-2">2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-3">3</button>

    <script src="index.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.css :

```
.btn {
  /* background-color: #4caf50; Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.btn:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

index.js :

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementsByClassName('btn-1').focus();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getElementsByClassName returns an array you can do this if you do like this

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementsByClassName('btn-1')[0].focus();
};
```

or you can use querySelector instead which targets the first element on the document

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.querySelector('.btn-1').focus();
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  Works perfectly.  Yes, I should've asked myself what the getElementsByClassName() function returns.  Lesson learned :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the autofocus attribute you can give to the button elements.

Refer the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_autofocus.asp#:%7E:text=The%20autofocus%20attribute%20is%20a,focus%20when%20the%20page%20loads.)

```
<button type="button" autofocus>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks I needed the button to show a specific background color on page load.  This autofocus will be useful to know.